# Front-end form (via page template) to control WordPress Customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, frontend

I'm working on a project where I want to prevent user access to the WordPress dashboard. As a result, there are some items the user needs to have access to in order to populate and configure the site.

**How do I create a front-end form (via WP page template) for editing theme Customizer settings like the header image and color settings?**

I already developed front-end forms (via page templates) for creating, editing and deleting posts. What I don't have is a way for the user to edit a handful of options available on the Customizer screen.

**UPDATE**

I found [update_option()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option/) to control site title/description, but still not sure about header image and color settings.

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Ha! I updated the above to be more clear ;-)

Comment: erm, no, I'm afraid you didn't. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try again ;)